# Are there any good style guides arguing for how much one should round corners with css?

Tags: css

I was having a discussion with a co-worker about what amount of rounding to put on elements on the web page we were designing, and it made me wonder if there are any good style guides or design manuals for these types of design questions?

Comment: Probably not. The amount of corner rounding you put on elements depends entirely on what you want the page to look like. There can be no general guidelines, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this ? [GUIDE](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/web-design/web-2-0-design-style-guide/)

The only thing I know was from an article I read from a Belgian Designer who is doing the fine tuning of Instagram and before that he had a company that was quickly taken over by facebook (Can't remember what they did).

The rule(s) that he applies are really simple:

1. Keep it simple not 500 different places for people to click or to focus too.
2. Use simple clean layouts the example he gave was one of the earlier facebook versions.
3. You can always improve a design but not by adding stuff as layout. By taking it down piece by piece.

That's all I can say about this.

**EDIT**

Found a good design site not just for a website. [SITE](http://startupsthisishowdesignworks.com/)

**EDIT 2**

After some surfing around I didn't really found a guide how sharp the edges or something like that should be but I did find when to use them: [SITE](http://designmodo.com/rounded-corners/)

Comment: The article didn't answer the question of rounded corners, but it did address the bigger question. Thanks for a good link.

Comment: Yeah, I was responding to the more general one. Because I thought a general view should give some ideas for the rounded corners question.
And that you were looking for a guide for that kind of design questions.

Comment: @EivindEidheimElseth I looked a bit further into this question because I really loved searching for a proper answer. I really like designing although I might not be the best or even good. Just a fun thing to do in my spare time.